# Can a dual Egypt/USA citizen with a Biometric Residence Permit in UK travel to/from UK with a US passport if BRP shows Egyptian nationality?

Tags: air-travel, uk, france, dual-nationality

I have dual citizenship of USA and Egypt. I am a student in England and hold a Biometric Residence Permit. My nationality on the BRP is Egyptian since I had applied for my Student Visa from Egypt.

Can I travel from London to Paris with my USA passport (no visa required) and return to England with my BRP?

Comment: You only need to use your BPR at the UK controls, you can use your American passport everywhere else in the EEA

Comment: @GayotFow that should be an answer.

Comment: @chx we need to see if a noob wants to create an answer. If not, yeah we can come in and answer it :) But give them a chance please...

Comment: @Crazydre nobody said 'stand-alone'. It provides leave-to-enter authority just like a visa affixed to a passport page.  And per my comment, it is recognised only by UK authorities.

Answer (score 3):

For entry to France, from [Consulate General of France in Chicago](http://www.consulfrance-chicago.org/Visa-requirements-for-American):

> American passport holders are not required to obtain a visa prior to visiting France -as tourists- for up to 90 days per semester (6 months).

For re-entry to UK, from [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits):

> You can use your BRP to confirm your:

- identity
- right to study or work in the UK
- right to any public services or benefits you’re entitled to

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use your US passport for France.

When re-entering the UK, present your Egyptian passport and BRP. This also goes for the Eurostar-run UK exit checks if going to France by train (before French border control)